# Swift - Alamofire - Combine - try to fetch access token if the endpoint returns 401 error code

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, access-token, combine

Ive got an API endpoint that i have got to take some data from but it needs an access token.
This access token is fetched from another endpoint of this api.

The access token expires every 2:30 hrs.

The way I am handling this is that every 2:20 hrs i have a a timer that fetches a new token. I know this is a bad practice since the user might turn off the internet during that fetching etc.

I am using an architectural pattern that splits my main app into 3 seperate layers.

A domain layer which contains all my models, use cases and repositories

A presentation layer which contains all my views and viewmodels.

And a Data layer that contains all my repository implementations , network constants, url builders and my API client where the request is made with alamofire.

My ApiClient is this :

```
public enum ApiClient {
    static func requestCodable<T: Codable>(_ urlConvertible: URLRequestConvertible) -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, NetworkErrorResponse>, Never> {
        return AF.request(urlConvertible)
            .validate()
            .publishDecodable(type: T.self, emptyResponseCodes: [200])
            .map { response in
                response.mapError { error in
                    let backendError = response.data.flatMap { try? JSONDecoder().decode(BackendError.self, from: $0) }
                    return NetworkErrorResponse(initialError: error, backendError: backendError)
                }
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

So , lets assume that i am making a call to an endpoint that needs the access token, and it fails because 3 hours have gone by ...
How can I say to my api client to fetch a new access token and then retry the endpoint that failed ?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not aware of your implementation I'll try to give you what I think is a possible solution:

```
public enum ApiClient {
    static func requestCodable<T: Codable>(_ urlConvertible: URLRequestConvertible, isRetry: Bool = false) -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, NetworkErrorResponse>, Never> {
        return AF
            .request(urlConvertible)
            .validate()
            .publishDecodable(type: T.self, emptyResponseCodes: [200])
            .map { response in
                response.mapError { error in
                    let backendError = response.data.flatMap { try? JSONDecoder().decode(BackendError.self, from: $0) }
                    return NetworkErrorResponse(initialError: error, backendError: backendError)
                }
            }
            .flatMap { result -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, NetworkErrorResponse>, Never> in
                if !isRetry && result == "401 error code" {
                    return requestAccessToken()
                        .flatMap({ 
                            // probably build a new urlConvertible with the new token
                            self.requestCodable(urlConvertible, isRetry: true) 
                         })
                } else {
                    return Just(result).eraseToAnyPublisher()               
                }
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

You could add a `flatMap` after your `map` and verify if you got the 401 error. If so, you would need to get the token, then use `flatMap` to re-request the `requestCodable`. You might notice there's a `isRetry` param, it is there to avoid loops.

Comment: This approach doesnt work for me ... 
It throws me this error : Cannot convert return expression of type 'Just<DataResponse<T, NetworkErrorResponse>>' to return type 'AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, NetworkErrorResponse>, Never>'

Comment: My answer is supposed to be some pseudocode, but to convert a Just to an anypublisher you have to call `.eraseToAnyPublisher()`.

Comment: Looks promising! But a couple things: 1. it should compile ;) , 2. you may consider to skip any `requestAccessToken()` request when there is one pending for the same realm already (i.e., requiring the same token). For example, a global actor could ensure this, but it should be doable with pure combine, too. From the code, its not clear how you access the token, of course it must be thread-safe and there must be no race conditions. Then, you better off checking the HTTP status code for 401. It should be clear, that all requests fail, when `requestAccessToken` fails. But this is OKish.